# Interrupts are firing when touching ground with metallic things

Tags: arduino, interrupts, atmega328p

I'm making a circuit on a breadboard (before SMD design) for a battery-powered device.
When USB is connected to any wall-adapter, the device wakes up when touching any ground wire on the breadboard with another metallic wire using my bare hands.

About the circuit:
On the Atmega328p-PU, an falling Interrupt on INT0 (with internal pullup) wakes it from deep sleep.
Normally, there are other ICs such as an TP5046 envolved, but I removed them all until this simple circuit and the problem still persists.
I wanted to do "Diode-Oring" between the battery and usb power, so the device doesn't use the battery while charging.

Does anyone know whats going on? Or if it's just a software error on the Atmega?

I think it has something to with my body capacitance, like touch sensors work. But even with stronger external pull-Up resistors and low pass filters on INT0, it fires the interrupt and wakes it up.

[image: Simplified Circuit]

Comment: I spy, with my little eye, a floating reset pin.

Comment: It's interally pulled up. Additionally, the MCU is programmed to immediately go to sleep at boot/reset, so this shouldn't be the problem :D

Comment: @Helyon I wouldn't trust internal pull-ups if you are seeing noise issues. They are very high resistance.

Answer (score 0):

People typically regard the internal pull-up resistor of the AVR reset pin as being slightly weak. I would consider putting a pull-up resistor of 4k7 on there as well as a capacitor of say 100nF or so as breadboards typically are noisy environments.

With noisy I mean that the connections on the breadboard can be a higher resistance than expected due to oxidation of the connections, glue on component legs from reels or general muck. This can makes the design more vulnerable to external influences.

When your design has a higher resistance than expected you can run into weird behaviors such as the one you have encountered now; by touching the ground wire you are transferring some of your charge to the circuit. This will change the voltage your circuit sees from the IO pins with regard to the ground plane.

Possible fixes are;

- Clean up component legs with some acetone or alcohol to prevent bad connections
- All ground and positive power supply connections should always go to or from the power rails on your breadboard; do not hop from ground pin to ground pin with jumper wires.
- Consider a higher quality breadboard as there are some low tier breadboards out there that will make your life difficult. Low quality breadboards are plagued with corroded / bad contacts.

I should also mention that it is typically considered a bad idea to work on electronics without some ESD protection; the charge you accumulate can be enough to cause a permanent malfunction of the electronics you are working with. Admittedly AVRs are tough beasts and can take some abuse but you should still take some precautions like an ESD wristband and an ESD mat if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! So you think that the circuit should work (the diode configuration)? I was already sure that the breadboard constillation is the problem, but I wanted to ask before ordering the pcbs.